# how to delete liferay's theme cache files?

Tags: liferay

i have developed a theme for liferay and i have deployed it.

but when i choose the theme it doesnt recognize it's styles and it is reading styles from previous theme caches.

how can i delete previous theme style caches?

Comment: Are you sure it is Liferay cache and not browser cache you are talking about? Try pressin Ctrl+Shift+R.

Comment: yah, i am sure.
i have tested it with different browsers.

Comment: Have you developed the theme as a hook plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i finally solved the problem.

it actually wasn't any sort of cache.

i just have to make everything_packed.css file. the theme was using the old file.